# How to use a SectionList with a large header title in React Native and React Navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

In iOS, the Large Title Header animates with the ScrollView when the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"` prop is set. It's a nice touch and I want to replicate this with the sticky headers of a `SectionList` (Or the sticky headers of a `FlatList` for that matter).

The issue is that when using a `SectionList` with the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"` prop, and `headerLargeTitle: true` set of the navigator, the headers of each section no longer stick to the top of the page!

Here's my code:

```
function MyScreen(props) {
    const { navigation } = props;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerLargeTitle: true
        });
    }, [navigation]);


    return (
        <SectionList
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
            sections={DATA}
            renderSectionHeader={header}
            renderItem={item}
        />
    );
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @jamesrogers93, did u find any solution?

Comment: @marco.marinangeli unfortunately I could not. It's a shame because it seems like it should be trivial